# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, facebook-unity-sdk

I got the error, whenever I run my app on my phone:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18680): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/app/***/base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5159)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4754)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4694)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5423)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
E/AndroidRuntime(18680):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I imported Facebook SDK, Firebase, Adjust, Unity Purchasing and Smartfox to my Unity Project.

I mentioned the problem in my previous topic and I think that opening new topic for the problem will be better.  Here is my previous topic which is related to this one for better understanding:

[Google.JarResolver.ResolutionException: Cannot resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-unity:1.0.0()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882947/google-jarresolver-resolutionexception-cannot-resolve-com-google-firebasefireb)

If you need further information, let me know.

Comment: looks like a native library mixup (related to google play services)

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882947/google-jarresolver-resolutionexception-cannot-resolve-com-google-firebasefireb/40976303#40976303

Answer (score 1):

try to

**1.** in your `build.gradle` put this:

```
defaultConfig {
    [...]
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**2.** Make your application class extend [MultiDexApplication](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html)

Comment: But I dont use Android Studio.  It is Unity and I dont use gradle files at all.

Answer (score 0):

See answer at [NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575810/nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-zzb)

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

You lack a jar package   play-server-basement.jar